# How can I fill a narrow gap in the countertop along the back of my new glass cooktop?

Tags: countertops, gap

I had to replace my glass cooktop. I checked the specs on a replacement, and ordered the one I thought would fit.  When I dropped it in the new stove top, I had a 7/8" gap.  The specs online were wrong.  The company I ordered it from said too bad, I should have measured it when the truck delivered, and refused delivery!
Now I have this huge gap.  And, since it is 29" long, no gap filler is long enough.  What can I do to hide this gap?[image]

Comment: My farmer's daughter of a mother would never let that stand with the retailer. Anyhoo, I'd look for a powder-coated metal strip that coordinates with the cooktop and install it with foam tape. It'll be challenging to coordinate with your countertop laminate.

Comment: Most cook top manufacturers also sell fillers specifically for this. I have seen them up to 36" and trim down to the size needed. If your cook top seller doesn't sell them, check with manufacturer. If not, I think box stores sell generic ones. That's the front, correct? It should of been installed tight to the front and the gap in back.

Comment: +1 for SS strip. Use the same strip top and bottom or all around to get a clean look.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I called the retailer 3 times.  And, was hung up on 3 times.  Left a review, it was denied.  I am going to take suggestion and contact the manufacturer.  As the daughter of 5 generations of home builders, I am not giving up.